# Apple App Sandbox System Access

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have an app that needs access to this file: ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.BFF8417E-284A-5C97-B9A8-FB91B9DA7642.plist

My app works perfectly fine without the sandbox enabled but when it is enabled it prevents access to this file as I can see in console. How can I let my app have access to this file while sandbox is enabled? Please HELP!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, you can't. That file contains some sensitive system settings, and is not accessible to sandboxed applications.

You could try adding a [temporary exception entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html) to give your application access to that file, but Apple will not approve an application with such an entitlement for store distribution. (Particularly because that file name is only correct for your computer! The UUID in the filename is different for every machine.)